# Powershell: Using Copy-Item to copy a file from TFS Server to another destination

Tags: deployment, powershell, copy-item

I have the command

```
Copy-Item -literalPath $file.ServerItem $destinationPath -recurse -force
```

where

> $file.ServerItem (path to file on tfs server that we want to copy)=
>   "$/TFSServer/MyPath/ToTheFile.vb"

and

> $destinationPath (test server path where file should be copied to) =
>   "\104server\MyPath\ToTheFile.vb"

I get the error

> Copy-Item: Cannot find path '$/TFSServer/MyPath/ToTheFile.vb' because
>   it does not exist.

This file exists. Please, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy directly from a TFS server path spec `$/TeamProjectName/path`.  There is no TFS Provider that I'm aware of.  You need to create a mapping of the TFS source to a local directory. Do a `tf get . /r` on that local dir to get all the source files.  Then whereever you see $/TFSServer in a ServerItem path, replace it with your local directory name.  Say you put the files in C:\TFSServer, then create your source path like so:

```
$srcPath = $file.ServerItem.Replace("$","C:")
```

Comment: Keith, is it possible to download the file to my machine using

$tfs.vcs.DownloadFile($serverPath, $fileName)

and then running copy-item on the downloaded file?

Comment: @AkinOkunrinboye I haven't used that particular API but that sounds like it would work.

Comment: I got this figured out. I was able to download the file and use copy-item. Your input helped. Thanks Keith :)

Comment: How did you that? I need a file from the server as well